# Why is Jekyll not loading my posts?

Tags: github, jekyll

I'm trying to create a simply gh-pages blog following [this tutorial](http://martinbean.co.uk/blog/2013/04/24/building-a-blog-with-jekyll/) but I'm my posts area keeps coming up blank. Any reason why this would be happening?

Here is the gh-page: 
http://ajrdesign.github.io/Readable/

Here is the repo with the code: 
https://github.com/ajrdesign/Readable/tree/gh-pages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file for your first test post is sitting at:

```
./_posts/first-post.md
```

In order for the GitHub Pages Jekyll engine to process it, the file name needs to start with a date string in the format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD-
```

Rename the file to:

```
./_posts/2013-07-25-first-post.md
```

That should get you started.

Comment: Great that worked! Only problem is now I'm getting a 404 error when I try to get to the actual content. Any ideas about that?

Comment: @AndrewRichardson - It looks to be working now. I see the content for your [Hello, World](http://ajrdesign.github.io/Readable/2013/07/25/first-post.html) showing properly.

Comment: Yeah got it working. It was just the github url was throwing things off.

Comment: Note that `YYYY-MM-DD_my_post_title.md` won't work! It has to be a *hyphen* and not an underscore, not only within but also *after* the YYYY-MM-DD. I tore out a few hairs over this one.